# vim plugin doesn't show in PlugInstall

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vimrc

I'm currently trying to customize my vim setup, which involves installing new plugins.
So I've edited my ~/.vimrc in order to install those plugins:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugin/bundle')                                                    
Plug 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'                                                                   
Plug 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'                                                                
Plug 'nvie/vim-flake8'                                                                     
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'                                                                       
Plug 'xolox/vim-misc'                                                                      
Plug 'xolox/vim-notes'                                                                     
call plug#end()·
```

However, when I type `:PlugInstall`, none of those plugins are listed. 
I need to execute the `:Plug <pluginName>` and then `:PlugInstall` again. But as soon as I exit vim and come back, plug-ins are gone. 
But they exist in the folder named in the beginning of the .vimrc file ('~/.vim/plugin/bundle').

I've been trying some all sorts of things but I'm out of options now...

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have a `plug#begin` block in any other Vim configuration file?

Comment: In the vimrc, there is no other `plug#begin` bloc. is any there other file I should be looking at?

Comment: (sorry for double comment)
I've been trying to find other files, and I found a `~/.vimrc.bundle` where everything is located... thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Following muru's comment, I've searched for other vim files, and I found a `.vimrc.bundles` file, where everything is listed.